# Spring MVC and Ajax Operation using JQuery

Tags: ajax, model-view-controller, spring

I have a JSP page called CreateProcessGroup.jsp and I use an annotation controller to map requests to CreateProcessGroup.htm to that page. But I'm having an interesting issue when I request the page from browser it works, when send a request using jQuery $.get method I get 404 (CreateProcessGroup.htm not found) is there a difference between two requests?

My JSP page just under WebContent dir and JS file under WEBContent/Jquery my function sending the request like below:

```
function SendCreateProcessGroupRequest()
{
var pid = $('#pid').val();
var description = $('#processGroupDescription').val();

var x = "/CreateProcessGroup.htm";
alert(x);

$.get(x, { pid: 62, description: description },
           function(data){
             alert("Data Loaded: " + data);
           });
}
```

Do I need to give the URL as `../CreateProcessGroup.htm`? Indeed I tried:

- /CreateProcessGroup.htm
- ../CreateProcessGroup.htm
- /../CreateProcessGroup.htm
- ../../CreateProcessGroup.htm
- /../../CreateProcessGroup.htm

My guess is DispatcherServlet can not map Ajax requests to Controllers but this is stupid isn't it?

How can i get rid of the situation?

Thanks all.

Comment: Where is the page that's running this, and where is CreateProcessGroup, both with respect to the root of the site?

Comment: yes CreateProcessGroup.jsp and the running page ProjectDetail are both under the WebContent folder.

Comment: @mehmet6parmak - What does `var x="CreateProcessGroup.htm";` (nothing before it) do?

Comment: i had some caching issues with tomcat i just used that to see whether my changes are reflecting or not is that matter?

Comment: @mehmet6parmak - Oh no that's fine, I just didn't see without a slash in your attempts list.  Without one i'll make a request *beside* the current page, if the pages/handlers are siblings in the hierarchy, it should work without the slash.

Comment: @mehmet6parmak - Excellent :) Converting this to an answer in hopes it helps the next person finding this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
var x = "CreateProcessGroup.htm";
```

If the page you're requesting is beside the one making the request there's no need for a path in front, it will (by default) make a request to the same path just with that page/handler on the end.